# Extend wpdb in other class - when use get_results for select gives me null

Tags: wordpress

I've added custom plugin (created by me) in WP in that plugin I have Class named BaseModel, which extends wpdb.

The problem here is everytime when I try to run query I get false or null or empty array as result.

```
class BaseModel extends wpdb{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
}

function get_destinations($limit, $order){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_relations";

    $result = $this->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
    var_dump($result); 
}

function get_total_destinations(){
}}
```

Can some one tell me what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the db credentials constants are defined?

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is not a full OOP solution but I solve this by adding global $wpdb into my functions.

```
class BaseModel {


function get_destinations($limit, $order){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_relations";

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
    var_dump($result); 
}

function get_total_destinations(){
}}
```

I hope you will find this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[More Info WordPress tests with wpdb](https://gist.github.com/rickard2/3135689)

```
<?php
class testWPDB extends wpdb {
function prepare( $query, $arguments ){
        return vsprintf( $query, $arguments );
    }
}

class UTCW_Test_Data extends WP_UnitTestCase {
protected $utcw;
function setUp(){
    $this->utcw = UTCW_Plugin::get_instance();
}

function getWPDBMock(){
    return $this->getMock( 'testWPDB', array( 'get_results' ), array(), '', false );
}

function test_author(){
    $instance[ 'authors' ] = array( 1, 2, 3 );
    $config = new UTCW_Config( $instance, $this->utcw );
    $db = $this->getWPDBMock( 'get_results' );

    $db->expects( $this->once() )
    ->method( 'get_results' )
    ->with( $this->stringContains( 'post_author IN (1,2,3)' ) );

    $data = new UTCW_Data( $config, $db );
    $data->get_terms();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you want to extend from it? If this class will always be loaded inside Wordpress files then you will have access to the global $wpdb.

```
class RandomClass {

    private $wpdb = false;

    public function __construct() {
        global $wpdb;

        if (is_object($wpdb)) {
            $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
        }
    }

    public function get_results($data) {
         return $this->wpdb->get_results($data);
    }
}
```